# sending variable to function to execute odbc SELECT

Tags: php, database, odbc

I am trying to execute the function below but does not display anything.

```
function displayNr($x){
    $sql="SELECT D4741 FROM table_x WHERE D4711='".$x."';       
    if (!$result = odbc_exec($pconn, $sql)) {
        echo "Query error! ODBC: ", odbc_error();
    } else {
        while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row["D4741"] . "\n";
    }
    }
}

displayNr('name');
```

However, if I remove the function it works correctly:

```
x='name';

$sql="SELECT D4741 FROM table_x WHERE D4711='".$x."';       
if (!$result = odbc_exec($pconn, $sql)) {
    echo "Query error! ODBC: ", odbc_error();
} else {
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row["D4741"] . "\n";
}
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: @user583162 - Tick the mark next to one of the answers to mark this as answered don't edit the title....

Answer (score 1):

$pconn is not set in the function.

Answer (score 0):

in the function, $pconn is a new local variable (with a scope of the function) and is not the same $pconn defined outside the function.  pass it in as a parameter:

```
function displayNr($x,$pconn){
    $sql="SELECT D4741 FROM table_x WHERE D4711='".$x."';       
    if (!$result = odbc_exec($pconn, $sql)) {
        echo "Query error! ODBC: ", odbc_error();
    } else {
        while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row["D4741"] . "\n";
    }
    }
}

displayNr('name');
```

**watch out for SQL injection!!!** your code is a perfect example of what not to do!!:

```
$sql="SELECT D4741 FROM table_x WHERE D4711='".$x."';
```

see this: [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) or just google it

Answer (score 0):

```
function displayNr($x, $pconn)
{
    $sql = "SELECT D4741 FROM table_x WHERE D4711='" . $x . "'";        //here " is remaining
    if (!$result = odbc_exec($pconn, $sql)) {
        echo "Query error! ODBC: ", odbc_error();
    } else {
        while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo $row["D4741"] . "\n";
        }
    }
}

displayNr('name');
```

Comment: Please add explanation to what your code does. Also use [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for different parts of your answer.